# Regular expression get the third element from a string

Tags: java, regex

Hello Im having trouble getting the third element of a string (F604080)

```
<sourceDocumentId>AX02_APF604_F604080</sourceDocumentId>
```

I have tried with this regular expression and variations, but i can manage to get 
F604080.

```
(?<=\w+_)\w+(?=\<)

(?<=\w+_\w+_)\w+(?=\<)
```

....

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't scan markup with regex. You want to use a dedicated parser to scan the XML, then use regex only on the value. After that if it's any consistent you can just grab a sub-string at the last index where the `_` character appears, `+ 1` (i.e. arguably you wouldn't need regex).

Comment: Java does not support infinite lookbehind like `(?<=\w+_)`. Your first regex could work using a finite lookbehind using a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) [demo](https://ideone.com/NYGenE) but if you could use a parser it would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need look behind or look ahead, instead just use this simple regex,

```
.*_(\w+)
```

and capture group 1.

Java codes,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "<sourceDocumentId>AX02_APF604_F604080</sourceDocumentId>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*_(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Didn't match");
    }
}
```

Prints this like you wanted.

```
F604080
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `regex` you can use something like `>\w+_\w+_(\w+)<\/`

   ```
   String str = "<sourceDocumentId>AX02_APF604_F604080</sourceDocumentId>";
   String code = null;
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile(">\\w+_\\w+_(\\w+)</").matcher(str);
   if (m.find()) {
       code = m.group(1);
   }
   ```
2. Simply use `substring()` operation

   ```
   String code = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, str.lastIndexOf('<'));
   ```
3. If later you parse `XML` with more element, you may use something like [`Java DOM Parser XML`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm), but here this is not the best option as you have only one element

Answer (score 0):

Can you just parse the string using "_" as separator and take the 3rd element ?

Answer (score 0):

Both of your regular expressions seems to be matching the given string.

Anyway you could be a little bit more specific with this one:

```
^(?:<\w+>)(?:\w+)_(?:\w+)_(\w+)(?:<\/\w+>)$
```

Be sure that the input is the string you think it is and no additional text is given after that.